# If $(A-I)^2=0$, then what is the determinant and trace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $(A-I)^2=0$, then what is the determinant and trace of $A$?

$(A-I)^2=0$ implies that all eigenvalues of $A$ is 1.

Is it true that $det(A)$ is the product of all its eigenvalues? Or it is only true when $A$ is diagonalizable?

Also, since $tr(A)$ is the sum of eigenvalues of $A$ only when $A$ is diagonalizable, I don't know how to calculate $tr(A)$ when I don't know $A$ is diagonalizable or not.

Comment: Hint: $tr(A)$ it's always the sum of the coefficients on the diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're wrong. The trace is *always* the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is *always* the product of the eigenvalues.

**EDIT**:

When $n=2$, write the characteristic polynomial $p(t)=t^2-(\text{tr}\,A)t + \det A = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)$ and you're done. In general, $$p(t)=\det(tI-A) = (-1)^n t^n + (-1)^{n-1}(\text{tr}\, A)t^{n-1}) + \dots + \det A = (t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\dots (t-\lambda_n),$$ and the same is true.

So, in your case, as you've noted, all the eigenvalues must be $1$, whether the matrix is diagonalizable or not, and so $\det A = 1^n = 1$ and $\text{tr}\,A = n\cdot 1 = n$.

Comment: Therefore in this case you mean $det(A)=tr(A)=1$?

Comment: Is $A$ a $2\times 2$ matrix? If so, what is the trace is both eigenvalues are $1$?

Comment: $A$ is a $n \times n $ matrix. Therefore $tr(A)=n$ since $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues, all of which are 1?

Comment: Can you at least change your answer, such that it fits the general $n \times n$-case?

Comment: @MooS: I have done so.

Answer (score 1):

$(A-I)^2 = 0 \implies$ all the eigen values are 1.Say $A$ is a $n\times n$  matrix then eigen value $1$ has algebraic multiplicity n.
This is for your knowledge:

There is a result which says $A\ n \times n\ Matrix\ is\ diagonalizable\ if\ it\ has\ distinct\ n\ eigen\ values$.

Here for $n$>1 this is definetly not the case. Also Converse of the theorem mentioned fails to hold when an eigen value with algebraic multiplicity greater than 1 has eigen space with dimension greater than 1.

As mentioned in first answer that the trace is always the sum of the eigenvalues and the determinant is always the product of the eigenvalues.

Now considering that the matrix $A$ is non-singular,
since all the eigen values are 1 the determinant would be $1$ and the trace would be $n \times1=n$.

If $A$ is singular than the determinant would be $0$ and the trace would be  sum of eigenvalues(which need not be neccassarily 1)$\times$ their algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: nice to see you active on math stack exchange. How are things at your end ? Enjoying parthi life once again ?

Comment: gud to see you too bro. I am enjoying studying maths everything is fine. give your email id let us speak there.